# SwaggerUI not showing validator badge on Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, swagger, iis-8, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a local SwaggerUI (v2.2.6) running on my local Tomcat server/windows box.
When I pull up a swagger definition with external references, it pulls it up fine. However the "Validator" badge does not show at the bottom right.

When I run the same Swagger definition file on SwaggerUI (v2.2.6) on IIS server/windows box, I can see the "Validator" badge claiming there to be an error.

Please help on why I am not seeing the "Validator" badge using the Tomcat instance?

I can share information, but I am not sure what will help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The validator badge triggers a call to another server passing the swagger file URL to be validated. 
If this URL is not accessible on Internet, it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, I think it explains. Will try out and confirm.